# Is libsqlite3-0 installed by default?

Tags: php, libraries

I'd like to know if libsqlite3-0 is installed by default, or if it is installed when running apt-get install phpmyadmin.

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04

I'd like to know what it is and why I can't uninstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libsqlite3-0` is present in both [Ubuntu 16.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) and [Ubuntu 14.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest) ISOs, and most packages from the ISO are retained on installation.

`apt-cache rdepends libsqlite3-0` lists a *lot* of packages, including `gnome-software`, `ubuntu-core-libs`, `unity-scope-click`, `shotwell`, etc.

So, yes, it is installed by default.